# How do I use the 'git describe' information to find a specific commit?

Tags: git

If I do 'git describe' in my directory I get the output:  1.0-24-g31cdd0f

How does one do a checkout at this same point in the revision tree after it is no longer HEAD?  How does one see the log for the 24 commits since the tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree with the second part of the answer provided by Greg Hewgill.

Output : **1.0-24-g31cdd0f** means that "1.0" is the latest reachable tag and it is 24 commits away from the recent commit "31cdd0f".
So, doing **git log 31cdd0f..** will not print anything. Because "31cdd0f" is the recent commit and leaving empty after ".." shows all commits till the recent commit.

The correct command should be

> **git log 1.0..31cdd0f**

. 
This will show all commits between the tag "1.0" and recent commit "31cdd0f".

Sources:

https://schacon.github.io/git/git-describe.html

https://schacon.github.io/git/git-log.html

Answer (score 5):

The commit that is tagged is the last part without the "g", so `31cdd0f`. You can checkout with:

```
git checkout 31cdd0f
```

or view the log of commits since the tag `1.0` with

```
git log 1.0..31cdd0f
```

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout 1.0-24-g31cdd0f

git log 1.0..1.0-24-g31cdd0f
```